# Creating a JSON Store For iPhone

Tags: iphone, json, core-data, persistence, store

We have loads of apps where we fetch data from remote web services as JSON and then use a parser to translate that into a Core-Data model.

**For one of our apps, I'm thinking we should do something different.**

This app has **read-only data**, which is **volatile** and therefore **not cached locally for very long**. The JSON is **deeply hierarchal** with **tons of nested "objects"**. Documents usually contain no more than 20 top level items, but could be up to 100K.

I don't think I want to create a Core Data model with 100's of entities, and then use a mapper to import the JSON into it. It's seems like such a song and dance. I think I just want to persist the JSON somewhere easy, and have the ability to query it. MongoDB would be fine, if it ran on iPhone.

Is there a JSON document store on the iPhone that supports querying?

Or, can I use some JSON parser to convert the data to some kind of persistent NSDictionary and query that using predicates?

Or perhaps use SQLite as a BLOB store with manually created indexes on the JSON structures?

Or, should I stop whining, and use Core Data? :)

Help appreciated.

Comment: I use this exact approach for an iPad app.  MonoTouch really helped get this done a lot faster...

Comment: ifwdev - ah cool, can you explain more? Did you store blobs? Why Monotouch?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When deciding what persistence to use, it's important to remember that Core Data is first and foremost an object graph management system. It true function is to create the runtime model layer of Model-View-Controller design patterned apps. Persistence is actually a secondary and even optional function of Core Data.

The major modeling/persistence concerns are the size of the data and the complexity of the data. So, the relative strengths and weaknesses of each type of persistence would break down like this:

```
    _______________________________
    |               |              |
  2 |               |              |
    |  SQL          |  Core Data   | 4
s   |               |              |
i   |_______________ ______________|
z   |               |              |
e   |               |              |
  1 |  Collection   |  Core Data   | 3
    |  plist/xml    |              |
    |               |              |
    -------------------------------  
              Complexity--->
```

To which we could add a third lessor dimension, volatility i.e. how often the data changes

(1) If the size, complexity and volatility of the data are low, then using a collection e.g. NSArray, NSDictionary, NSSet of a serialized custom object would be the best option. Collections must be read entirely into memory so that limits their effective persistence size. They have no complexity management and all changes require rewriting the entire persistence file.

(2) If the size is very large but the complexity is low then SQL or other database API can give superior performance. E.g. an old fashion library index card system. Each card is identical, the cards have no relationships between themselves and the cards have no behaviors. SQL or other procedural DBs are very good at processing large amounts of low complexity information. If the data is simple, then SQL can handle even highly volatile data efficiently. If the UI is equally simple, then there is little overhead in integrating the UI into the object oriented design of an iOS/MacOS app.

(3) As the data grows more complex Core Data quickly becomes superior. The "managed" part of "managed objects" manages complexity in relationships and behaviors. With collections or SQL, you have manually manage complexity and can find yourself quickly swamped. In fact, I have seen people trying manage complex data with SQL who end up writing their own miniature Core Data stack. Needless to say, when you combine complexity with volatility Core Data is even better because it handles the side effects of insertions and deletion automatically.

(Complexity of the interface is also a concern. SQL can handle a large, static singular table but when you add in hierarchies of tables in which can change on the fly, SQL becomes a nightmare. Core Data, NSFetchedResultsController and UITableViewController/delegates make it trivial.)

(4) With high complexity and high size, Core Data is clearly the superior choice. Core Data is highly optimized so that increase in graph size don't bog things down as much as they do with SQL. You also get highly intelligent caching.

Also, don't confuse, "I understand SQL thoroughly but not Core Data," with "Core Data has a high overhead."  It really doesn't. Even when Core Data isn't the cheapest way to get data in and out of persistence, it's integration with the rest of the API usually produces superior results when you factor in speed of development and reliability.

In this particular case, I can't tell from the description whether you are in case (2) or case (4). It depends on the internal complexity of the data AND the complexity of the UI. You say:

> I don't think I want to create a Core
>   Data model with 100's of entities, and
>   then use a mapper to import the JSON
>   into it.

Do you mean actual abstract entities here or just managed objects? Remember, entities are to managed objects what classes are to instances. If the former, then yes Core Data will be a lot of work up front, if the latter, then it won't be. You can build up very large complex graphs with just two or three related entities.

Remember also that you can use configuration to put different entities into different stores even if they all share a single context at runtime. This can let you put temporary info into one store, use it like more persistent data and then delete the store when you are done with it.

Core Data gives you more options than might be apparent at first glance.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, a good breakdown of where the strengths of Core Data kick in.

Yup, we've got 100's of entities (classes), so it sounds like Core Data will be a lot of work.

Comment: Well, if you have 100s of logically separate chunks of data which all require different behaviors, it's going to be a lot of work anyway. If you use, say, SQL, you would need 100s of tables to store them. More likely, you actually need a just one or a handful of generic entities that you could use to generate a tree structure of arbitrary complexity.

Comment: Thanks. When you say generic entities, do you mean storing the JSON in BLOBs in those entities? Since the JSON we're fetching contains many different "entities", I'm not sure what you mean by using generic entities to create a tree structure.

Comment: JSON only has a handful of actual logical objects: Objects, Arrays, values:(stings,numbers, true, false,null). So, at most, you would only need 7 entities to model any arbitarily complex JSON structure.  If you don't understand, ask another question and I'll try to flesh the idea out in another answer. I am pretty sure some the JSON frameworks out there already do this.

Comment: Also, Marcus Zarrus, who literally wrote a book on Core Data, provided the following example of how to convert JSON to and from Core Data by generating hundreds of entities on the fly. I've never used it but it certainly gives you an idea of how easy it is to implement even the most free-wheeling object graph. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362323/json-and-core-data-on-the-iphone

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying, makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I use [SBJson](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) to parse JSON to NSDictionaries then save them as .plist files using `[dict writeToFile:saveFilePath atomically:YES]`.  Loading is also just as simple `NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:saveFilePath]`.  Its fast, efficient and easy.  No need for a database.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how SBJason compares to http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/?

Comment: Sorry about the delay in response - it's the same code, Tobin.  I just call it be the main class name.

Answer (score 0):

[JSON Framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) is one. It'll turn your JSON into native NSDictionary and NSArray objects. I don't know anything about its performance on a large document like that, but lots of people use it and like it. It's not the only JSON library for iOS, but it's a popular one.