# What about performance in core data?

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I would like to write an application based on core data, but I don't know if it's worth, there will be several tables of a few or several thousand data.

What is the situation at the front?

Comment: This previous answer of mine might provide some guidence: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237943/creating-a-json-store-for-iphone/5249674#5249674

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few thousand records isn't that many in the grand scheme of things, and so is likely to be fine. Though without knowing exactly what you want to do with the data or what platform you're running it on, it's difficult to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to remember about Core Data is that it isn't primarily a persistence API i.e. one primarily concerned with getting data onto and off disk like SQL. It is primarily an API for creating the entire model layer for a Model-View-Controller (MVC) design app. As such, it provides a complete data management solution from persistence to object-graph management to integration with the UI.

Core Data is such a comprehensive solution that in Cocoa using bindings, it is possible to create entire apps without writing any custom code.

Any performance you might *hypothetically* lose in persistence operations with Core Data is almost always overshadowed by the performance gains of the object-graph management and UI integration.